# Angular2 - Add class to item on click

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of list items and would like to highlight each one once it's clicked. This is easy for me to do in jQuery or even JavaScript but I'm lost when it comes to Angular2.

```
<ul>
   <li [attr.data-selected]="false" (click)="highlightItem($event)" [class.highlight]="isHighlighted($event)" *ngFor="#item of items"> {{item}} </li>
</ul>
```

My component

```
export class HelloWorld {
    items = ["pineapples", "apples", "tomatoes", "bread"];

    highlightItem(event) {
        event.target.setAttribute("data-selected", "true");
   }

   isHighlighted(event) {
       return event.target.getAttribute("data-selected") == "true";
    }
}
```

Not sure where my mistake is or if I'm using a wrong method

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make an array in your class to store highlight status of an item:

```
hightlightStatus: Array<boolean> = [];
```

Declare local variable in the template associated with ngFor:

```
<ul>
   <li [attr.data-selected]="false" 
       (click)="hightlightStatus[i]=!hightlightStatus[i]" 
       [class.highlight]="hightlightStatus[i]" 
       *ngFor="let item of items, let i = index"> 
       {{item}} 
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me but I believe you are correct. Probably has to do with plunker and my version of angular

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Your code looks like Angular 2 beta (`#item of items`, `#` was used in beta). Mine - **Angular 2 RC1**

Answer (score 14):

If I am understanding the question properly, I believe you can also use the render from angular2 to get a similar code to your example code. For my own project I did the following:

In my template I have:

```
<li role="presentation" (click)="userTypeSelect($event)" ><a href="#">Local</a></li>
```

In my component I then have:

```
import {Renderer} from '@angular/core';
//other imports

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private render:Renderer) { }

      userTypeSelect(event:any){
        event.preventDefault()
        this.render.setElementClass(event.target,"active",false);
      }

}
```

It is worth noting though that I am not using this for a list of items, however I believe it should still work.

Reference to the Renderer: [Renderer Api Docs](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html)

Comment: in my case it didnt work. so i had to use `setElementAttribute`. 
`let oldClasses = event.target.getAttribute('class');
 this.renderer.setElementAttribute(event.target, "class", oldClasses + ' selected');`

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to achieve this, and all are very simple.

**Examples:**

```
<li *ngFor="let n of list" (click)="select(n)" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(n)}">
  <a>{{n}}</a>
 </li>

 select(item) {
      this.selected = item; 
  };
  isActive(item) {
      return this.selected === item;
  };
```

**Only using html**

```
<li *ngFor="let n of list" [class.active]="clicked === n" 
         (click)="clicked = n">
       <a>{{n}}</a>
    </li>
```

**Add class on click and remove if we click on the same**

```
select(item) {
   this.selected = (this.selected === item ? null : item); 
};
```

**Only using html**

```
<li *ngFor="let n of list" [class.active]="clicked === n" 
       (click)="clicked = (clicked === n ? null :n)">
     <a>{{n}}</a>
   </li>
```

[More info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/add-class-to-active-element-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 2):

By your question title, you want to add a new **class** to the `li` when it's clicked, right?

If that's it, then it can be simple like this:

```
 <ul>
   <li (click)="highlightItem($event)" *ngFor="let item of items">
     {{item}}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

---

```
export class HelloComponent {
  public items: string = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Grapes', 'Watermelon'];

  public highlightItem(event) {
    if (! event.target.classList.contains('highlighted')) {
      event.target.classList.add('highlighted');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It May help you

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  values:Object[];


  ngOnInit() {
    this.values=[{name:'Alex',done:false},{name:'Jon',done:false}];
  }

  completed(i:number){
    if(this.values[i])
      this.values[i]['done']=!this.values[i]['done'];
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let v of values;let i='index'" 
        (click)='completed(i)'
        [class.checked]="v.done" 
        >       
        {{v.name}}<span class="close">×</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```