# Highlight list item and remove with Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a list of items and when the user clicks on an item, this item gets highlited. We do this by simple adding ***ngIf="object.shouldHeight"** and works.

**My Problem:**

When the user clicks on another item, the previous selected item should be **unhighlighted**

**My first idea for the solution:**

The first solution I thought was to iterate through all items, change their status to `false` and then set the current status to `true`. This would work!

**My second idea for the solution:**

The other was to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891752/angular2-add-class-to-item-on-click), but this is not working as toogle, means, when I click on a next item, the previous one is still highlighted.

---

How can I achieve this in **Angular2** without writing loops in my code?

---

**UPDATE:**

I achieved this, althought I still think it could be more elegant:

In my component I have the following function:

```
public showButtonbar(i: number) {
    this.hightlightStatus = []
    this.hightlightStatus[i] = true;
}
```

And that is my click event, where **i** is the index:

```
(click)="showButtonbar(i)"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bind list item's CSS class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#class-binding), so that when the condition is true Angular2 adds that CSS class, that defines highlited item style.

E.g.:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowIdx = index;"
  [class.myhighlight]="rowIdx === highlightRowIdx">
</tr>
```

The above adds CSS class `myhighlight` to the table row when the row index is equal to `highlightRowIdx` member variable of the model/controller.

Comment: What about the click event? Where does it take place and what should I set to it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://dev-plaza.com/list-component-custom-html-elements-selection-highlighting) is a short list-component-guide. This component is also able to hightlight the selected element. Maybe you can find some help there.